# Estimating probablity

Tags: probability

Class consists of 30 students, all born in the same year that this year has 366 days.Find the best estimate of the probability that the number of people who were born on the same day is not more than 20.

I try: 
$X$ - number of people that were born $i-th$ day. 
$X_i$ - number of people that they were born $i-th$ day
$EX = EX_1+...+EX_{366}$

But, Could you help me compute $EX_i$ ?

Answer (score 0):

$X_i$ is the number of students born on the $i$-th day. Then
$$
P(X_i \le 20) = \sum_{j=0}^{20}
{ 
{{30}\choose{j}} \left(\frac{1}{366}\right)^j \left(\frac{365}{366}\right)^{30-j} 
}
$$
Notice that the events $\{X_i \le 20\}$ are not mutually exclusive, but the events $\{X_i > 20\}$ are mutually exclusive. Therefore the probability that there exists $i^*$ such that $X_{i*} > 20$ can be calculated via summation: 
$$
P(\exists i^*: X_{i*} > 20) = \sum_{i=1}^{366} P(X_i > 20) = 
\sum_{i=1}^{366} \left( 1 - P(X_i \le 20) \right) = 
366 \left( 
1 -
\sum_{j=0}^{20}
{ 
{{30}\choose{j}} \left(\frac{1}{366}\right)^j \left(\frac{365}{366}\right)^{30-j} 
} 
\right)
$$
So the result is
$$
P(\forall i: X_i \le 20) = 1 -
366 \left( 
1 -
\sum_{j=0}^{20}
{ 
{{30}\choose{j}} \left(\frac{1}{366}\right)^j \left(\frac{365}{366}\right)^{30-j} 
} 
\right)
$$